# Tastypie foreign key recursive relation loading an internal foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, tastypie

In Tastypie I've set up the following recursive / reflective connection:

```
origin = fields.ToOneField('self', 'origin', null=True, full=True, full_detail=True, full_list=True)
```

In my application I have a class of type Creation that can be connected to a previous instance / record. I want to retrieve this recursive connection, however the tricky part is that each such creation is connected to a user who created it.

While the line code above works fine, the origin field (which is of type 'Creation') has a reference (using a foreign key) to another table - Users, and I cannot seem to load it. I'm trying to preform this load of a creation including it's origin the the origin creator using a single trip to the database. How can I achieve this?

Thanks